# Examples where Lovasz' Local Lemma can not be applied

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

> In class the following examples of events $A_i$ were presented as NOT suited for the application of [Lovász local lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma) (we did the asymmetric case as Wikipedia calls it) for fixed $n \ge 2$:
>
> 1. Let $\Omega := \{s \in \{1,\ldots,6\}^n \mid \sum_{i=1}^n s_i \text{ is even} \}$. We choose an $s \in \Omega$ uniformly at random and let $A_i$ be the event that $s_i$ is odd.
> 2. Let $\Omega := \mathcal{S}_n$, i.e. the set of permutations of $[n]$. We choose a permutation $\sigma \in \Omega$ uniformly at random and let, for each $i \in [n]$, be $A_i$ the event that $\sigma(i) = i$.

I can intuitively see that the events $A_i$ described here are NOT mutually independent. (But I do not see how to argue this in a formal way.) But why is Lovasz Lemma not applicable in these examples? I mean we could just connect all vertices in the dependency graph, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there's too much dependence. As a general rule, LLL only works if the events are mostly independent (or in other words the dependancy graph is mostly sparse — how sparse it needs to be also depends on the probabilities).

In your case, for $(1)$, we can check that for each event $A_i$, it is not the case that $A_i$ is independent of $(A_j)_{1 \leq j \leq n, j \neq i}$, because clearly if we condition on $s_j$ (for $j \neq i$) being odd, this forces $s_i \equiv n-1 \ \text{mod} \ \ 2$ since we have the constraint $\sum s_i$ even. Hence each vertex in the dependancy graph must have degree at least $1$. Given a vector $(x_j)_{j=1}^{n} \in [0,1)^n$, the LLL condition requires that for each $i \in [n]$, $P(A_i) = \frac{1}{2} \leq x_i \prod_{j \in \Gamma(i)}(1-x_j) \leq x_i(1-x_{j^{*}})$ where $j^{*}$ is a fixed neighbour of $i$. By symmetry, we get $\frac{1}{2} \leq x_{j^{*}}(1-x_i)$ as well, so that $\frac{1}{2} \leq \min(x_{j^{*}}(1-x_i), x_i(1-x_{j^{*}}))$. It is not hard to see this is a contradiction (one of the four numbers on the RHS is $\leq 1/2$, and all are $<1$).

For $(2)$, the events $(A_i)$ admit pairwise dependence, since for $j \neq i$, conditioning on $\sigma(i) = i$ increases the probability of $\sigma(j)=j$ (since $\sigma(j)$ has one fewer member of $[n]$ it can map to). Hence the dependancy graph is complete, so we'd need an inequality of the form $\frac{1}{n} \leq \min_{i} \left(x_i \prod_{j \neq i, 1 \leq j \leq n} 1-x_j\right)$ for $x_k \in [0,1)$. Let $x_{i^{*}} = \min_{i} x_i$, then clearly $\min_{i} \left(x_i \prod_{j \neq i, 1 \leq j \leq n} 1-x_j\right) = x_{i^{*}} \prod_{j \neq i^{*}, 1 \leq j \leq n} 1-x_j \leq x_{i^{*}} (1-x_{i^{*}})^{n-1}$. By a differentiation the latter expression is maximized at $x_{i^{*}}=1/n$, so that $x_{i^{*}} (1-x_{i^{*}})^{n-1} \leq 1/n(1-1/n)^{n-1} < 1/n$, so we have no such inequality.